# Getting prisma args by passing table name as string

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I'm trying to get the prisma args tu use in a function. i know i can get the table by passing the table name as a string int the following way:

`function (tablename: string) { await prisma.[tablename].findMany({here comes the args}) }`

i want to know if there is a way for me to get the query args by passing only the table name so that i can call my fucntion like

`function (tablename: string, args: *prismafindmanyargsforthattable*){ await prisma.[tablename].findMany({args})`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to concatenate and create the name of the type you want. See this example:

```
function find<Table>(table: string, query: Prisma[Table + "FindManyArgs"]): any extends Table
```

Hope this helps. Good studies!